# UISplitView remove app tint color

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7, uiviewcontroller, uisplitviewcontroller

My app is based on a `UISplitViewController` on iPad.
There is a functionnality which add a second `UISplitViewController` **over** the first.
But this remove the apptint.

I've tried the following code in the first split view when going back on first split view, but it does not work:

```
-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
   UIWindow *appWindow = [[UIApplication sharedApplication]keyWindow];
   [appWindow setTintColor:[UIColor redColor]];
}
```

I heard there is a bug (8276014 in apple bug report) that seems to match my issue.

Any help?

Answer (score 0):

You can also set an app’s tint color in Interface Builder. The Global Tint menu in the Interface Builder Document section of the File inspector lets you open the Colors window or choose a specific color.

or

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    self.window.tintColor = [UIColor redColor];
    return YES;
}
```

or

In iOS 7, tint color is a property of UIView. iOS 7 apps often use a tint to define a key color that indicates interactivity and selection state for UI elements throughout the app.

When you specify a tint for a view, the tint is automatically propagated to all subviews in the view’s hierarchy. Because UIWindow inherits from UIView, you can specify a tint color for the entire app by setting the window’s tint property using code like this:

Setting the tintColor property by using the appearance proxy APIs is not supported in iOS 7.

```
[[UIView appearance] setTintColor:[UIColor redColor]];//iOS 6
```